# NextJS file downloads broken for PDF + images

Tags: next.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download files via Google Drive's V3 API. I am using NextJS + App Router.

Plain text documents will download correctly and are viewable, but when trying to download JPEG/PDF/other files I will get an error when opening. I am assuming this is an encoding issue when downloading via my API but am stumped on my next steps.

The files in question are viewable directly from Google Drive, and I am passing the correct mimeTypes to the API route (application/pdf, image/jpeg, etc).

Client side:

```
const downloadFile = (f: { id: string; name: string; mimeType: string }) => {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/download`, {
            method: 'GET',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'mulitpart/form-data',
             },
            params: {
                fileId: f.id,
                fileName: f.name,
                contentType: f.mimeType,
            },
            responseType: 'blob',
        })
        .then((res) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]))
            const link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href = url
            link.setAttribute('download', f.name)
            document.body.appendChild(link)
            link.click()
            link.parentNode?.removeChild(link)
        })
}
```

Server side:

```
export const GET = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    try {
        const jwt = cookies().get('access_token')?.value as string
        const fileId = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('fileId')
        const fileName = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('fileName')
        const contentType = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('contentType')
        if (!contentType || !fileName || !fileId)
            // respond with bad req
        const gDrive = new GDriveApi(jwt)
        const { data: file } = await gDrive.getFileById(fileId as string, true)

        const response = new Response(file, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${fileName}`,
                'Content-Type': contentType,
            },
        })

        return response
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

GDrive:

```
export default class GDriveApi {
    private api: AxiosInstance
    constructor(jwt: string) {
        this.api = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3',
            params: { key: process.env.GAPI_KEY },
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` },
        })
    }

    async getFileById(fileId: string, download = false) {
        return await this.api.get(`/files/${fileId}`, {
            params: {
                includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
                supportsAllDrives: true,
                alt: 'media',
            },
            responseType: download ? 'blob' : undefined,
        })
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!